# Muting a dummy audio track generated through an Oscillator

Tags: javascript, webrtc, media

I have a dummy audio track which is defined as follows:

```
let silence = () => {
  let ctx = new AudioContext(), oscillator = ctx.createOscillator();
  let dst = oscillator.connect(ctx.createMediaStreamDestination());
  oscillator.start();
  return Object.assign(dst.stream.getAudioTracks()[0], {enabled: false});
}
```

The problem is, whenever I try to disable the corresponding WebRTC audio track in Senders, the audio keeps 'playing' on the other end, even though the reported status of the track, i.e. of its 'enabled' flag is set to 'false'.

Any callbacks that need to be supported by the 'virtual' track ? So that I turn off the oscillator etc?

Either I'm doing something terribly wrong or it's not cool that such 'security' would need to be supported from the within.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try following code, it seems like that the **enabled** flag set to false is not enough:

```
let silence = () => {
  let ctx = new AudioContext(), oscillator = ctx.createOscillator();
  let dst = oscillator.connect(ctx.createMediaStreamDestination());
  oscillator.start();
  let track = Object.assign(dst.stream.getAudioTracks()[0], {enabled: false});

  return {
    track,
    stop: function() {
      oscillator.stop();
      oscillator.disconnect();
    }
  };
};
```

To implement your own custom stopping mechanism you can use something like that:

```
let silence = () => {
  let ctx = new AudioContext(), oscillator = ctx.createOscillator();
  let dst = oscillator.connect(ctx.createMediaStreamDestination());
  oscillator.start();
  let track = Object.assign(dst.stream.getAudioTracks()[0], {enabled: false});

  let trackPlaying = true;

  return {
    track,
    setEnabled: function(enabled) {
      trackPlaying = enabled;
      if (!trackPlaying) {
        oscillator.stop();
        oscillator.disconnect();
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Thank you'll try in a sec, I've just set on a journey of implementing a full-blown virtual media device as an ECMA6 class, with a variety of options, it  will take a couple of more minutes and I'll report.

Comment: would you be so kind to shed little bit more light which methods are being overloaded here? point me to docs, which would be the function to resume? 'start'?

Comment: looks like here you overload 'stop' of track (..) and once stopped, well, the track cannot be resumed am I correct?

Comment: For the documentation see here:

Stop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioScheduledSourceNode/stop

WebRTC: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API
WebAudio: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API

Comment: after some playing around I do not really see how to pass the custom object you've defined into a MediaStream, I used to instantiate it like so new MediaStream([black(...args), silence()])

Comment: I've updated my answer with a stop mechanism, check it out, I hope that's what you mean

Comment: is setEnabled with any relationship with the existing native APIs? I mean I know that I could stop the oscillator, the point of this thread is making the mechanics compatible with the existing API i.e. possibly overriding the enabled property of the returned track, I suppose..